# Firebase Storage Rules Private URL for authenticated users (without downloadURL or library)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Is it possible display an image (`<img/>`) in my Web application privately without using `getDownloadURL` or the `@firebase/storage` library?

For example I tried the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{userId}/images/{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

and my html page contain an image like:

```
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{projectId}.appspot.com/o/{userId}/images/yolo.jpg?alt=media/>
```

This page is only presented to authenticated user but still, even after successful login I still get a `403` when I try to render the image like displayed above.

My guess is that the img https request doesn't contain any information about the authorization, that's why it fails.

Therefore my question, is there any way to get a private storage file without using the Firebase library to download the image/file?

Comment: Is your web app running in the cloud? If not, why can't you just use images from the server's local disk and write some auth logic for serving the images?

Comment: Thank for your reply. App run on the client side and "I have" to link it from an image tag as the html content is, to some extension, edited by the user.

Comment: The entire app is running client side including the server/back-end? I take it these images are also dynamically uploaded or are these just static images you want to display but restrict to certain auth'd users? You could try requesting the image data in an AJAX/fetch and setting an `<img>` tag's source to the Base64 encoded binary data URI you make from getting the image, that way you have full control over the headers/cookies sent to retrieve it.

Comment: Thx again. Unfortunately I can't really query through Ajax, it has to be, kind of, a given static image tag (of course complexity is different but that's the way I could narrow the requirements).

Comment: I don't think there are any easily-accessible URLs that effectively "encode" authentication privileges in them that can be checked in security rules. I'm sure you can imagine the security issue with that, with respect to the possibility of sharing those URLs outside the time and space where they are intended to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Doug and I'm agree. After a good night of sleep, I understood that there are not other way than performing a request as user1538301 also explained above. Fortunately I'm using some component and therefore I was able to find a solution without altering my users content. Will post my solution as soon as I cleaned my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments section of my question **NO** it isn't to achieve my goal without fetching the image through a request the client side.

However, I managed to find a solution which fits the needs of our application, therefore let me share it.

First thing first, a bit more content. The content of our application, a WYSIWYG presentation editor, is generated by the user and might also, to a later stage, be publicly shared. That's why we have the need to have private and public assets.

Furthermore, the shared content is HTML and is also what the user is editing, therefore it isn't, or at least for me it wasn't, that straight forward to attach requests in order to fetch the images.

Fortunately, we do use Web Components, which, thanks to shadowed content, allowed me to obfuscate what I do not need when the image is public.

Respectively, in this case, instead of using `<img/>` element I used our component `<deckgo-lazy-img/>`.

```
npm install @deckdeckgo/lazy-img
```

That's why I improved the component and added a new `boolean` property `custom-loader`. When turned to `true`, instead of displaying the image when intersecting the viewport, the component will bubble an events `custom-load` which could be intercepted in order to load the image with a custom code.

Therefore I just add to find my components element in my app and turn the property to true. Good things to notice also, properties are not reflected in the dom, therefore my original question is kind of solved as the content of the user won't change.

html:

```
<deckgo-lazy-img img-src='https://firebasestorage..'/>
```

javascript:

```
document.querySelector('deckgo-lazy-img').customLoader = true;
```

Finally, I add to add an event listener to intercept the custom event:

```
document.addEventListener('customLoad', this.onCustomLoad, false);
```

Custom even which provide the information `imgElement` (the shadowed image) and `imgSrc` (the actual source of the image provided as attribute of the componenent).

And then process the loading of the image with the Firebase Storage while authenticating the request with the token of the logged user, as I wanted to keep my above rules.

```
try {
  const rawResponse: Response = await fetch(detail.imgSrc, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${your_user_auth_token}`
    }
  });

  if (!rawResponse || !rawResponse.ok) {
    console.error(`Image ${detail.imgSrc} can not be fetched.`);
    return;
  }

  const blob: Blob = await rawResponse.blob();
  detail.imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

(where `detail` is the custom event detail).

Our project is open source, here the related [commit](https://github.com/deckgo/deckdeckgo/pull/586/commits/001cca60a9dbb85728c3f2b38d6c223a8a5dc10d) I added to the PR I'm working on.